# Subgroups of abelian-by-finite groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am trying to prove that a subgroup of a abelian-by-finite group is also abelian-by-finite. I am not sure if I can use the same procedure that is used for a subgroup of a  finite-by-(abelian-by-finite) group?

Remark: We say that a group $M$ is abelian-by-finite if there exists an abelian normal subgroup $N$ of $M$ such that $M/N$ is finite.

Comment: I think "abelian-by-finite" means groups of the form $G\times H$, where $G$ is abelian and $H$ is finite, right? If it is the case, your statement might be false, because not all subgroups of $G\times H$ are of the form $G^*\times H^*$, with $G^*\leq G$ and $H^*\leq H$.

Comment: Consider, for example, the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. This group has $p+1$ subgroups of order $p$, and only two of them are of the form $G^*\times H^*$.

Comment: We say that a group $M$ is abelian-by-finite group if there exists an abelian normal subgroup $N$  of  $M$  such that $M/N$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are classes of groups that are closed under taking subgroups (such as abelian groups and finite groups: any subgroup of an abelian group is abelian, and any subgroup of a finite group is finite) then the class of $\mathcal{X}$-by-$\mathcal{Y}$ groups (i.e., groups $G$ with a normal subgroup $N$ such that $N$ is in $\mathcal{X}$ and $G/N$ is in $\mathcal{Y}$) is closed under taking subgroups.

For let $H$ be a subgroup of such a group $G$. Then $H\cap N$ is a normal subgroup in $\mathcal{X}$, since it's a subgroup of $N$, and $H/(H\cap N)$ is in $\mathcal{Y}$, since it's isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/N$.

Comment: @ http://math.stackexchange.com/users/88262/jeremy-rickard

Comment: Jeremy, can you please explain why $H\setminus(H \cap  N)$ is finite? Why this is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G \setminus N$??

Comment: @Lola I think you've got an answer in the other thread you posted, but to explain it in a slightly different way: let $\varphi$ be the composition of the inclusion $H\to G$ and the canonical epimorphism $G\to G/N$. Then it's easy to see that the kernel of $\varphi$ is $H\cap N$, so the image of $\varphi$, which is a subgroup of $G/N$, is isomorphic to $H/\ker(\varphi)=H/(H\cap N)$.